# Open/ read rw2 image with color using python?

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone open this raw file with color? It is an image and I tried everything with numpy, rawpy, fastrawviewer etc. It is almost 3 days I try to open with color but I failed.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
fd = open('img.rw2', 'rb')
ROWS = 2000
COLS = 2000
f = np.fromfile(fd, dtype=np.uint8,count=ROWS*COLS*4)
im = f.reshape((ROWS, COLS,4))
fd.close()
cv2.imshow('img.rw2', im)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Your image seems inaccessible.

Comment: Google Drive doesn't allow me to download it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks. I have forgot to choose who to share the file with

Answer (score 1):

If your image was 2000x2000 RGB it would be 12,000,000 bytes, but it is 16,000,000. So try reading it as RGBA, rather than RGB.

```
im = np.fromfile('img.raw', dtype=np.uint8).reshape((2000,2000,4))
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

If the image was saved as RGBA, you will need to correct the ordering in OpenCV because that will use BGRA - use `cv2.cvtColor()`.

Comment: Thanks for answering but  `´im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB)` shows a different image, it changes like the format of the image. For example the background of original image was blue but the color here is black. Do I need to change anything else? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Not sure how it's supposed to look. Maybe try `cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA` to retain transparency and then save as PNG to retain transparency.

Comment: Thank you so much I will try to retain transparency and see if it will work or not.